# Archlinux boot time

Tags: linux, boot, performance, time, arch-linux

I have Archlinux installed in my netbook. I want to reduce the boot time to less than 10 seconds. Is this possible? Do you have any success in reducing the boot time to a larger extent?

I am aware of the link [Arch Improve Boot performance](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improve_Boot_Performance), yet to try it. Is there any other pointers to improve the boot time further? or any success/failure experiences?

Comment: Found a related link. Boot in 5 seconds!!! http://lwn.net/Articles/299483/

Comment: Same question in another stackexchange site: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16737/how-to-optimize-arch-linux-boot-time

Comment: http://www.bootchart.org/ looks interesting.

Comment: Can you be more specific.  I can "boot" to /bin/sh in about 1st and xvesa + wm + terminal in about 2s, but I get the feeling you would want more than that.

Comment: As some have mentioned, you CAN get your boot time on linux distros like Arch to sub 2s (I've done it before as has one of my friends...we were competing to get lowest boot time), but you have to shut off a lot of boot processes and scrape out unneeded modules (as mentioned in the answer below).

systemd dramatically cuts down on boot time, but if you want to optimize your boot time, figure out what you need/don't and eliminate only unecessary stuff to get everything running you want/need as soon as you log in.

Answer (score 3):

Boot time depends enormously on the services you start up.  Cutting anything back that you don't need is a big part of the process.  Given that you are starting from an Arch linux position, it is very likely that you have already done this, by simply not putting stuff into DAEMONS that you don't need.  Consider also doing an `lsmod` to see what modules are loaded for your hardware and seeing if there are any you don't need.

Another thing you can do is be very aggressive with the start up of those thing that are important.

I think [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) is a good parallel and aggressive init process and is a good starting point for reducing startup times.